# How to access specified fields value of a struct using operator[]

Tags: c++, vector

Let's say I have a struct with a bool field

```
struct pBanana {        
        bool free;          
    };
```

Now I have another struct that contains a vector of the pBanana struct

```
struct handler_toto {

    std::vector<pBanana > listBananas;

};
```

Now I would love to return how many times the **boolean free** is false in the listBananas

```
int someFunction (mainHandler& gestionnaire)
{ 
return std::count(gestionnaire.listBananas.begin(), gestionnaire.listBananas.end(), gestionnaire.listBananas.operator[/*How to do it here */]);
}
```

After consulting the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)  I'm having difficulties understating how to use `operator[]` properly in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you can't use `operator[]` to do this.

You could do this using `std::count_if` (not `count`) and a *lambda function* a.k.a. *anonymous function*:

```
return std::count_if(
    gestionnaire.listBananas.begin(),
    gestionnaire.listBananas.end(),
    [](const pBanana &b) {return b.free;});
```

`std::count_if` will call your function for each item in the list, and count the number of times it returns `true`.

Comment: Pardon my knowledges in c++ , thank you for your interest in helping !

Comment: "*you can't use `operator[]` to do this*" - yes you can, you just have to loop through the vector manually. `std::count_if()` just does the looping for you.

Comment: Your lambda needs to use `return !b.free;` instead, as the OP wants to count the number of boolean that are false, not true

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::count_if()`, like demonstrated in immibis's answer, is the best option.

To answer your question, to use `operator[]` properly, you have to loop through the vector manually, eg:

```
int someFunction (mainHandler& gestionnaire) {
    int count = 0;
    std::vector<pBanana> &bananas = gestionnaire.listBananas;
    size_t size = bananas.size();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (!bananas[i].free) // <-- operator[] called here
            ++count;
    } 
    return count;
}
```

Or, you can use iterators instead  and not use `operator[]` at all:

```
int someFunction (mainHandler& gestionnaire) {
    int count = 0;
    std::vector<pBanana> &bananas = gestionnaire.listBananas;
    for(std::vector<pBanana>::iterator iter = bananas.begin(); iter != bananas.end(); ++iter) {
        if (!iter->free)
            ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```